# Javascript constructor returning a bound function?

Tags: javascript

A few of my colleagues and I have been experimenting with returning bound functions from constructors.

This allows us to make these functions that 'build' other functions, without calling them `buildDispatcher` or `prepareAddition`. Let me give an example:

```js
function addition(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function buildOffsetter(a) {
  return (b) => addition(a, b);
}

var offsetter = buildOffsetter(42);

console.log(offsetter(10));
```

If I were to use a constructor instead, I could do this instead:

```js
function addition(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function Offsetter(a) {
  return (b) => addition(a, b);
}

var offsetter = new Offsetter(42);

console.log(offsetter(10));
```

Now, a more real-life example might look like this:

```js
function dispatchDataToUrl(url, data) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    error: () => console.log(`An error happened when sending [${data}] to [${url}].`) 
  });
}

function buildDispatcher(url) {
  return (data) => dispatchDataToUrl(url, data);
}

var dispatcher = buildDispatcher("http://stackoverflow.com");

dispatcher("stackoverflow rocks");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

which could be built like this:

```js
function dispatchDataToUrl(url, data) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    error: () => console.log(`An error happened when sending [${data}] to [${url}].`) 
  });
}

function Dispatcher(url) {
  return (data) => dispatchDataToUrl(url, data);
}

var dispatcher = new Dispatcher("http://stackoverflow.com");

dispatcher("stackoverflow rocks");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, we really like not having these "build"-functions that return bound functions.

My question is, is there any downside to this? Is there some hidden pitfall that we haven't stumbled into yet?

Comment: Resource wastage aside (see georg's answer/[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description)), when I see `new Something()`, I'm expecting an object, not a function. The builder functions are much clearer to me.

Comment: But isn't that merely a question of habit? Resource wastage aside. Habits are as habits are. If you're used to seeing specific patterns, other patterns might seem less clear until you are used to seeing those.

Comment: Yeah, of course it's a stylistic choice - not trying to imply you're *wrong* to do things this way! I just don't see the value, personally.

Comment: I understand your intention. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x = new Something()` where `Something` returns an object is exactly<sup>*</sup> the same as `x = Something()` except that `new` wastes a few resources allocating a new object which is ultimately thrown away. So the only actual difference between your `buildOffsetter` and `Offsetter` is their naming. As to downsides, allocating memory you're not going to use is a bad idea.

---

<sup>* Provided `Something` is a constructor, and you don't rely on its `this`.</sup>

Comment: I usually find it harder to have good naming, than keeping a low memory footprint. Didn't Phil Karlton say something clever about naming once? :)